# where should you put JWT token at angular side

Tags: spring-boot, cookies, spring-security, jwt

i am new to software industry,recently i am trying to understand JWT with Spring boot,Spring security,i understood you should not put your token in localstorage ,or in session as it will defeat the aim of JWT.so is it good idea to put JWT token in **cookies** at angular.Thank You For your help in advance

Comment: Please could you separate out your questions into a single question per post? The title appears to have two questions in one.

Comment: sorry but i separated the question thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for making the change.